# Wordpress: Adding user meta

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to add some custom fields to each Wordpress User Profile. I am using the following hooks:

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'myfunc');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'myfunc');
```

The problem with these, is they only display for the profile which is logged in. For example, I am logged in as the super admin, yet I cannot edit these fields for my subscribers. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently there were 2 other hooks which had to be used with this in order for it to work correctly

```
personal_options_update
edit_user_profile_update
```

Rookie mistake!